# SyntaxError when starting an otree project on Virtual Studio Code (MacOS)

Tags: macos, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, syntax-error, otree

I started using VSC to code with otree a couple of weeks ago and everything was going smoothly. 
Today, I started a new project so I went to Terminal and typed

```
cd otree
```

Followed by

```
otree startapp project
```

And then I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/T/anaconda3/bin/otree", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "/Users/T/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/otree_startup/__init__.py", line 75, in execute_from_command_line
    configure_settings(DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/Users/T/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/otree_startup/__init__.py", line 153, in configure_settings
    user_settings_module = import_module(DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/Users/T/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 674, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 781, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 741, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/T/oTree/settings.py", line 68
    },
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And I'm not sure what this means or how to solve it. Thank you!

*** UPDATE ***
I uninstalled everything and now it's even worse. 
I start with

```
pip3 install -U otree
```

Then,

```
otree startproject oTree
```

But then, I get

```
-bash: otree: command not found
```

Comment: you probably need to type `otree startproject name_of_your_project` first

Comment: I tried it, got the same error!

Comment: what version of oTree do you use?

Comment: I updated otree and python yesterday.

Comment: have a look at your settings.py (line 68): perhaps indeed there is a typo there?

Comment: I uninstalled otree and somehow it worked out. Thank you!